# How to tell if all colSums or rowSums (or other aggregate) of a data frame are equal in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, equality

I don't understand this behavior:

```
> a = c(1,1,1,1,1)
> (a==1)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c(6,7,8,9,10))
> df
  a  b
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
> colSums(df)
 a  b 
15 40 
> ndf = apply(df, 2, function(col){col/sum(col)})
> colSums(ndf)
a b 
1 1 
> (colSums(ndf) == 1)
    a     b 
 TRUE FALSE 
> typeof(a)
[1] "double"
> class(a)
[1] "numeric"
> typeof(colSums(ndf))
[1] "double"
> class(colSums(ndf))
[1] "numeric"
> b = c(1,1,1,2,1)
> all(b==1)
[1] FALSE
> (b==1)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> all(a==1)
[1] TRUE
> all(colSums(ndf)==1)
[1] FALSE
```

Why doesn't the same test that "works" on `a` and `b` NOT work on `colSums(ndf)`?

Comment: this is most likely a numerical issue, have you tried `sprintf("%.10f",colSums(ndf))` ?

Comment: Although I can't reproduce your problem in this case anyway. `(colSums(ndf) == 1)` gives me two `TRUE`s on Win7 64 bit, R 3.4.2.

Comment: Can't reproduce either on MacOS, R 3.4.0; `all(colSums(ndf)==1)` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: @thelatemail -- that is exactly what is going on. Duh. `(abs(colSums(ndf)-1) < 1e-10)` gives `TRUE TRUE`. If you make it an answer I can accept.